# Which Push notification service provider to use for Android which doesn't use FCM

Tags: android, push-notification, android-push-notification

I am working on an Android app for a client. App won't be deployed on Play Store. Also, the customer doesn't want to create a Firebase account.
Which Push notification service provider can I use which doesn't have any dependency on Firebase.

Comment: Pushy - https://pushy.me. Its free to try for up to 100 devices. Be aware to receive push notifications whilst a device is in Doze mode requires the user to disable battery optimsations for your app, if not then the device wont get the notification - this is not a problem with FCM however (surprise, surprise).

Comment: Check these push notifications services - https://www.mobiloud.com/blog/best-push-notification-services